# beginner: python unpack

Tags: python

Disclaimer: I am a beginner in python but have Drupal programming experience.

I have this:

```
f = [1.jpg, 2.jpg, 3.jpg] #unknown amount at runtime
```

and I need to do this

```
call(['c:/program files/ABBYY FineReader 10/finereader.exe',f])
```

BUT instead of simply ending the call with f, it should do this

```
call(['c:/program files/ABBYY FineReader 10/finereader.exe', 1.jpg,2.jpg,3.jpg])
```

How can I unpack f? Is unpacking the right approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would this work? By performing `+` on two lists, you get a new list back that is the concatenation of the first list with the second.

```
call(['c:/program files/ABBYY FineReader 10/finereader.exe'] + f)
```

You can also append further arguments to the list in-place with the `extend()` method:

```
command = ['c:/program files/ABBYY FineReader 10/finereader.exe']
command.extend(f)
call(command)
```

Comment: I voted you up anyway. :) I probably won simply because “concatenation” was faster to type than its meaning. I will have to remember that an indented code block seems to get better formatting.

Comment: Haha! I distracted you, and one-upped your answer with a more detailed discussion of list assignment and sublists! _grin_ BTW, I'm responsible for your upvote here.

Comment: I'll see you and raise you an `extend()` call.

Comment: Ahh, you have me beat. The `extend()` call is much more commonly useful than sublist assignment. I was just trying to figure out how to work the OPs 'unpacking' idea into it.

Answer (score 1):

Do this: `call(['c:/program files/ABBYY FineReader 10/finereader.exe'] + f)`

Adding together two lists results in a new list that has the elements of the first followed by the elements of the second.

Another thing you can do is this:

```
reader_exec = ['c:/program files/ABBYY FineReader 10/finereader.exe']
reader_exec[len(reader_exec):] = f
call(reader_exec)
```

I think that's more verbose and difficult to understand, and wouldn't recommend it. But the general technique of replacing a sublist (in this case the empty list at the very end) with another list can be very useful in certain situations.